# Java: create a separate sorted Arraylist while keeping the original list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following function. It receives an array list.

On my GUI, I have a buttons that toggles between two states. One that sorts the list in alphabetical order, and one that prints out the list in the order of appearance.

Note that I am filling the arraylist from an external file, and that I am opening this file in another function, so re-opening the file and re-filling the list array with its content seems unnecessary.

As it is now, the list sorts itself alphabetically but won't print back in the original order.

How can I create a separate list that will hold the sorted list while keeping my original list in order?

Thanks

```
sortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (sortButton.getText().equals("Sort by Route")){
                    sortButton.setText("Sort Alphabetically");
                        Journey value = mapper.get(objectName);
                        ArrayList stops = value.getNewStop(); //loads an arraylist into stops
                        System.out.println(stops);
                    }
                }

                else if (sortButton.getText().equals("Sort Alphabetically")){               
                    sortButton.setText("Sort by Route");                
                        Journey value = mapper.get(objectName);
                        ArrayList stopsSorted = value.getNewStop(); // use the arraylist attribute
                        Collections.sort(stopsSorted);
                        System.out.println(stopsSorted);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the `ArrayList` holds `String`s:

```
ArrayList<String> stopsSorted = new ArrayList<>(value.getNewStop()); // use the arraylist attribute
Collections.sort(stopsSorted);
System.out.println(stopsSorted);
```

As you can see, we pass the `ArrayList` that we don't want to modify into the constructor of a new `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @JonGoe pay attention that this method does a shallow clone, it's not an issue for an immutable type(which `String` is) but in case you're holding mutable objects inside well ...

Comment: @niceman As long as OP isn't modifying anything in the `List` other than sorting it, they'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clone the original list and sort the clone.  Then you just switch what you show - sorted list or original list.

```
ArrayList stopsSorted = stops.clone()
Collections.sort(stopsSorted);
System.out.println(stopsSorted)
```